# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database: 15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app using React-Native and I'm trying to connect it to my Firebase database. When I try to run my code (i.e., react-native run-android), I get the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database: 15.0.0.
```

I've looked at the solutions proposed in [Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091687/could-not-find-com-google-firebasefirebase-database9-2-0) and [react native Could not find com.google.firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081380/react-native-could-not-find-com-google-firebase), but neither have worked for me so far...

Here is my top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Here is part of my app level build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database: 15.0.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your gradle and android build plugin the add the `google()` repo to your project `build.gradle`.

Update your gradle version to at least version **4.4** by changing your `gradle-wrapper.properties` in gradle folder to:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Update build plugin and add `google()` repo to your build.gradle so that your project build.gradle will become like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    // update to version 3.1.3
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()

        // the following is the same as google()
        //maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made these changes but I'm now getting the following error: > Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've made the changes according to your edits but I'm still getting the same error... Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems the `google()` line is not recognized. Try reverting back to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`

Comment: Thanks! I needed maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }  in both the all projects repositories and the buildscript repositories. I've also updated to the latest gradle version (4.8). I'm now running into a different issue though... but I'll create a separate question for that.

Comment: Here is a link to my new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976840/could-not-find-com-google-firebasefirebase-database-16-0-1. I would really appreciate your help on this if possible!

Answer (score 1):

Add google() in this block:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()   // add this
        // others here...
    }
}
```

It's the repo required for all Android, Firebase, and Play services dependencies.  You should add it here too:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

[Read more about it here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven).

Comment: Thanks Doug! But now I'm getting the following error:

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Caravan'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade your gradle.  Latest version is 4.8.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I've updated my gradle to version 4.8, but I'm still getting the same error... What else could it be?

Comment: There are no other requirements.  Are you sure you're running with gradle 4.8?  What change did you make, and how are you verifying that they're effective?

Comment: Thanks Doug! I was able to solve this problem, but now I'm running into another one... Here's a link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976840/could-not-find-com-google-firebasefirebase-database-16-0-1. I would really appreciate your help on this is possible!

Comment: Your other problem is exactly like this one.  You're missing the google repo.

Comment: I've added the google repo but I'm still getting the same problem... I've gone into more detail in my other question.